# Extract just the number

Tags: r

I would like to know how do I extract just the number 4 of `a`?

```
> a<-subset(a, data ==datas & category == chosse, select="PCP")
> a
# A tibble: 1 x 1
    PCP
  <dbl>
1     4
```

Comment: Try `a[['PCP']]` or `a[, 'PCP']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$` to extract the data value as vector.

```
res <- subset(a, data ==datas & category == chosse)$PCP
res
```

Or

```
with(a, PCP[data ==datas & category == chosse])
```